# Sitefinity 4.2 - Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: sitefinity-4

I am trying to pull up a Sitefinity 4.2 project and get this error when doing so.

> Server Error in '/kadytv' Application.
>
> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> Source Error:
>
> > An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> > [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
> >        DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_OpenAccessMetaDataProvider_aec2ba29742646bdae02fcb21a4945ef.Initialize(String providerName, NameValueCollection config, Type managerType) +405
> >        Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1.InstantiateProvider(IDataProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType, ExceptionPolicyName policy, ManagerBase`1 manager) +2005
> >        Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1.InstantiateProvider(IDataProviderSettings providerSettings, ExceptionPolicyName policy, ManagerBase`1 manager) +74
> >        Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1.SetProvider(String providerName, String transactionName) +510
> >
> > [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
> >        System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
> >        System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +117
> >        System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +247
> >        System.Activator.CreateInstance() +88
> >        Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ManagerBase`1.GetManager(String providerName, String transactionName) +123
> >        Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.SystemManager.Initialize() +232
> >        Telerik.Sitefinity.Abstractions.Bootstrapper.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) +293
> >        Telerik.Sitefinity.Abstractions.Bootstrapper.Bootstrap() +386
> >        Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinityHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +114
> >        System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +575
> >        System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352
> >        System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +407
> >        System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +375
> >
> > [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
> >        System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11642112
> >        System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
> >        System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4865877

I tested the 4.2 install with an empty project and all works ok but this custom 4.2 project is not happy for some reason.

Anyone else have experience with this and able to resolve it.

Comment: Solved: I copied all the DLLs from an empty project and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [this forum thread](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/541962/unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-connected-with-entitydatasource) on Microsoft Connect useful.

I have a feeling that your problem is related to the entity Framework DLL's; so try setting your `Local Copy` to `true`.

If you can't find how to do this, edit your `csproj` file and find `<Private>False</Private>` line and set to `true`.